# National Women's Soccer League API

Tags: data-request, api, sports

I am looking to build an iOS application for the [NWSL](http://www.nwslsoccer.com/index.html) that displays live sports scores and schedules as well as other data you would expect to find in any sports app. I have found plenty of sources that will give out data either for exorbitant prices or don't even offer data for the NWSL, mostly the latter.

If anyone knows of a good API for women's soccer that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any good API available for this data, but looking at [the schedule on the NWSL website](http://www.nwslsoccer.com/schedule), it seems to be published as a fairly simple HTML table. You could probably just make your app scrape it with not too much difficulty. Not the ideal solution, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I am responding to this a few years too late, but in case anyone else stumbles onto this question you should know that per NWSL's terms of use you are not allowed to scrape anything off their site. Make sure to always check out a site's terms of use before doing any scraping.

https://www.nwslsoccer.com/terms